# d3 drag in pane and position

Tags: jquery, d3.js, charts

I have just started working on d3 and want something as shown in the mockup. Charts will be dragged and dropped from left panel to right panel. If they are dropped(like Chart 4) under existing panel(Chart 2) then another line chart should be added in the same panel(multi line chart will be created with existing and new chart). If it is dropped outside then a new panel will be created and positioned appropriately. There are many d3 examples available but couldn't find anything closer to this.
Please point me if there is any existing example or can someone help to get started or is it even possible to achieve this using d3? Will nvd3 be more helpful in this scenario.

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao53n.png)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [gridster](http://gridster.net/). There're also articles online on using it with d3 such as [this](https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/drag-and-drop-visuals-in-your-interactive-dashboard-gridster-d3-js/). If the d3 paths/shapes need to trigger creating new charts, then you can handle that via your own function calls on [drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) events

Other than the above you'd need to reduce your problem to more discrete chunks as it is quite broad at the moment.

Comment: Gridster looks great, but the question here is about dragging the chart on existing chart and then it should create multiline chart and adjust axis. Also calculating mouse event to find if it is actually dragged inside existing chart or new area.

Comment: As i said in my response "...If the d3 paths/shapes need to trigger creating new charts, then you can handle that via your own function calls on drag events" with a link to documentation on drag events.